# How anonymous callback function access data returned by calling function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if this question is too naive to ask or already been answered. I am confused about javascript anonymous callback function which can access data returned by calling function. E.g:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write('hello world');
    response.end();
});
```

Can anyone explain how anonymous function's arguments are accessing the data returned by `http.createServer()` function? Or I am getting something wrong? Apologies in advance for any mistake as this is my first question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer function is getting the callback as argument, and it calls it with some arguments. Maybe a simpler example will explain it better:

There is a function that takes another function as an argument, and calls it with a 'value' string passed as argument:

```
function fn(cb) {
    cb('value');
}
```

Now when you run:

```
fn(function (val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

you will have the string 'value' printed but not because the second (anonymous) function has access to variables or values inside of the `fn` function, but because the anonymous function got some data passed as its argument - called `val` in this example.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying it to this extent. I was looking it other way around. Now i get it.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't *returned* by `createServer`.

`createServer` will, at some point in the future, call the function and pass it arguments at the time.

You can't see the code that does that (well, you can, since Node.js is open source and you could dig it out if you really wanted to), but you don't need to since its behaviour is documented.

---

Compare to this:

```js
var thing = example_that_takes_a_callback(function(request, response) {
  console.log(request, response);
});

function example_that_takes_a_callback (callback) {

    callback(1,2);
    setTimeout(function () { callback(3,4); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () { callback(5,6); }, 2000);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply : the anonymous function you pass as an argument to createServer() is being called inside the code of this latter with the appropriate arguments request & response.